# Styling a paragraph within a <div>

Tags: html, css

How do I style the paragraphs for every `<div>` with `id="FormFields"`?

```
<div id="FormFields">
    <div id="headerform">
        PAtient information<p>Please enter you full legal name</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to have multiple divs with an ID of FormFields you should make it a class instead. Valid HTML only allows for one ID per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
#FormFields 
{

}

#FormFields p
{
  color:blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks , do you know whats the standard width the webpages should be ( body selector..

Comment: @user1091438 - Depends upon your design. You may set 90% to 95%.

Answer (score 0):

```
#headerform p {
    // styling for p tag here
}
```

Or you can use a CSS3 attribute equals selector:

```
p[name="FormFields"] {
    // styling for all p tags where name = FormFields here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the rule of CSS. If you want multiple elements with the same name, use class (`.FormFields`) instead of ID (`#FormFields`).

Then style it with the answers given by others.